# Does everyone in a party need to be 62 or over to qualify for the Marriott senior discount?

Tags: hotels, senior-travel

I'm booking a trip with my mother and mother-in-law, who are both over 62 years old. The hotel we're staying in is a Marriott, which offers a [senior discount for travelers 62 and over](https://www.marriott.com/specials/senior/default.mi).

> Traveling is one of life’s great pleasures – especially when you take advantage of Marriott’s senior discount. If you're 62 years or older, you can save 15% or more on your room rate at Marriott brand hotels worldwide, seven days a week. So, start planning your trip and plan to save.

What I can't figure out is whether everyone traveling needs to be 62+ or if only one person does. There are specific restrictions mentioned on the hotel's rate information page

> Marriott Senior Discount
>
> - Available to guests 62 years of age or older.
> - Proof of age eligibility required at check-in.
> - Limit of two rooms per night.

Maybe I'm being too literal but I don't want to check in and have them tell us that we can't have the rate for both of the rooms we're booking because only two members of our party are seniors and then charge us the current rate for the hotel.

I found [this](https://theshortfinal.com/what-you-need-to-know-about-marriotts-senior-discount/) on another site but it was the only place I've seen it mentioned that only one person has to be a senior and even then it's not 100% clear.

> #### Do I have to travel with a senior to get the discount?
>
> Yes, you sheister. In practice, you won’t get ‘carded’ 100% of the time as it really depends on the mood of the desk agent. Otherwise, Marriott requires valid photo ID showing the date of birth for the senior.
>
> This brings me to my next point. You **do not** need to book the reservation under the senior’s name in order to get the discount. You can book it and add them as a guest with you. Just be prepared to have the senior’s photo ID showing date of birth for the desk agent.

Is there any official clarity on this?

Comment: Why not call and ask them? ;)

Comment: @NicoHaase I'm one of those silly millennials who are afraid of non-text interaction. Calling people on the phone is scary. ;) Anyway, now Travel.SE has a useful question and answer that wasn't here before and that unambiguously helps the people of the internet know the answer without calling anyone. Wins all around!

Comment: Catija (diamond) is a new contributor. Welcome to the stack, and hope to see you more often!! Maybe network wide mods should not have the "new contributor" tagging, but anyway, GJ.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

That description seemed ambiguous to me too, so I called the phone number on the [Marriott Senior Discount](https://www.marriott.com/specials/senior/default.mi) information page.

The representative told me that as long as one person is 62 or over, the room itself qualifies for the senior discount, regardless of the ages of the other  members of the group.

She also said that if two people in the group are at least 62, you can have two rooms at the discounted rate, and it doesn't matter how old the people are who actually sleep in either room.  Two is the maximum number of rooms allowed under that part of the policy.  After that, a senior would have to sleep in any additional rooms.

Anyone in the group can make the reservation, and pay for it, as long as they give the name and age of the senior. When checking in, the senior must sign for the room and present their identification.

Comment: Most of the time it really boils down to "get them on the phone and get an answer from the horse's mouth... Well done anyway. Sometimes one can't get them on the phone, and now they can just google it. +1